# OpenJPA enhancer or load-time weaver

Tags: ant, openjpa, load-time-weaving

I am getting this exception .

```
<openjpa-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT-r420667:1227246 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Could not locate metadata for the class using alias "Customer". This could mean that the OpenJPA enhancer or load-time weaver was not run on the type whose alias is "Customer". Registered alias mappings: "{Customer=null}"
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:363)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getClassMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:169)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.resolveClassMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:147)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:216)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:186)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateType(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:179)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.access$500(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:66)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.populate(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:1685)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.populate(JPQLParser.java:55)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.populateFromCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:148)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:652)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:633)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:599)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:661)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.getOperation(QueryImpl.java:1487)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.getOperation(DelegatingQuery.java:123)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:228)
[9/11/12 14:12:57:958 EDT] 0000019a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:278)
```

I have an enhancer task in my Ant Script.

I see my classes are enhanced and the dize of class file is increased, But I still get the above exception.

Answer (score 0):

List your persistent types in your persistence.xml file.

Comment: I have that here is my persistence.xml   <persistence-unit name="BIRSDataSource">
  <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
  <class>cms.bres.birs.vo.Customer</class>

Comment: For giggles, try making sure that your Entity class (Customer) has been loaded prior to executing the query?

Comment: Thanks Rick, How Do I make sure that the Class is Loaded ? I there any way to do that ? In my WAS , I have set Application Load First Class loader Sequence

Comment: An easy way is to create a Customer when your application starts up.